# Using match in react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Within my `<Switch />` I dynamically create routes with a dynamic path in which ideally will all load the same component.

I have a JSON object like so:

```
{
  "products": [{"name": "car"}]
}
```

Which just contains an array of products which currently only has one product with the name "car".

In the `<Switch />` I loop through the products to create a route like so:

```
{
  ProductHelper.getAllProductPages().forEach(product => {
          console.log(product.name);
          return (
            <Route path={'/' + product.name + '/:id' } component={Search} />
          );
  })
};
```

The console log prints out "car" perfectly so i see no issue with getting the product name. However, when I navigate to /car/test I'd expect this to load the Search component but it doesn't.

When I create a route like this:

```
<Route path='/car/test' component={Search} />
```

This loads the Search component perfectly to prove that the component doesn't issues.

I really don't understand what im doing wrong here, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If you were to change to: `<Route path={'/' + product.name + '/test' } component={Search} />` it would work a well... the issue is the dynamic `:id`

Comment: @SakoBu Is there any alternatives? Why is the :id an issue?

Comment: I've changed it to what you suggested but this still doesn't work. I'm leaning more towards the foreach not making it work now but cant seem to understand why

Comment: instead of forEach try to use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1 (recommended)

Use `map` (no return needed):

```
{
  ProductHelper.getAllProductPages().map(product => <Route path={'/' + product.name + '/:id' } component={Search} />)
};
```

`map` builds an array (of components typed Route in this case) and returns it, and that is exactly what you need. When you use `forEach` it is considering that function as a component to render - and that's wrong.

### Option 2 (less recommended)

Alternative way, using `forEach` instead of `map`:

A function returns an array of Components:

```
renderRoutes() {
    const productRouters = [];
    ProductHelper.getAllProductPages().forEach(product => {
      console.log(product.name);
      productRouters.push(
        <Route path={'/' + product.name + '/:id' } component={Search} />
      );
})
      return productRouters;
}
```

And then rendering it:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                this.renderRoutes()
            } 
        </div>
    )
}
```

**But I would recommend using `map` (first option) in that case anyway.**

Comment: Thank you for going in to more detail (code wise). This works!

Comment: @KTOV edited with more information and another option (maybe it will fit other situatios of yours)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.forEach` you should use `.map`, because forEach doesn't return an array. Map does

Comment: Changing to .map still hasn't resolved the issue. Looking at the console.log it appears car is being logged twice, not once although the product array only has one item in it. To prove that 2 routes with the same path isn't the cause of the issue I created 2 routes with the same paths and they worked as expected (loaded the same component).